# sentry issues not being linked to source map

Tags: devops, sentry

I am using https://github.com/nuxt-community/sentry-module which in turn is also pushing the code for source map to work (internally https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-webpack-plugin).

I have enabled the integration for gitlab. I have created a `.sentryclirc` file with `project`, `org` and `token` as variables to fill.

The token has `proj:read` `proj:write` and `proj:release` permissions enabled.

This is my config for sentry webpack

```
            release: pkg.version, // 1.0.0
            // dryRun: isDev,
            setCommits: {
                repo: "company_name/project_name",
                auto: true,
            },
```

I am using my `SENTRY_DSN` properly.

I am able to push a source map under release 1.0.0, and when I go to an issue it is tagged as 1.0.0.

Under the release tab, I get the message `Releases aren't 100% set up` and redirects me to [tag an error](https://docs.sentry.io/workflow/releases/#configure-sdk). I don't really understand what it is suggesting I do. The config should just use the recent commit.

I look under the issues tab and the issues are tagged with the version 1.0.0 and say it is linked to it. Yet, the minified version is still showing up.

Looking around I click on the link `View new issues seen in this release in the stream` to see what issues I have filtered for that version. I looked at the query in the url and the query is `first-release-1.0.0`.

I am not sure why it defaults to filtering it like that.

This leads me to believe that the release I am deploying isn't by synced up with the issues that sentry is pushing.

Comment: Same issue here